# java "=+" compiles but it does not affect any variable

Tags: java, sum, operator-keyword

I wanted to increment an integer by adding another one , but i wrote "=+" instead of "+=" . and i saw that it compiles but it does not do anything . or does it ?

```
a=3
b=5
a=+b

print a >>> 5
```

What is the reason ?

Comment: This snippet prints out `5`, not `3`. [Ideone](http://ideone.com/huASw7).

Answer (score 4):

since `=+` is not any operator (but `+=` is).

So `a=+b` is equals `"a = +b"` and `b = +b` that will be `a = b` in the end.

may be you are looking for  `a += b` which equals `a = a + b`

Answer (score 0):

Think of the operation

```
a=3;
b=5;
a=-b;
```

That seems perfectly reasonable so it would be strange to disallow +b, I also very very occationally use this as a piece of self documentation (much like I sometimes put in +0), meaningless but harmless to the program but may have some meaning to a human observer